# Concrete5.7 Absolute urls

Tags: concrete5

So now with c5.7 how would we go about forcing c5 to spit out absolute urls? And what is the base url method or static class? `URL::to('assets/css/website.min.css');` spits our the url as a relative url with the dispatcher. Which is correct according to its implementation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any available method for this in the API as in most cases the relative URLs are enough.

Can't you just prepend the `BASE_URL` constant in front of your link? Or create your own helper class to prepend it automatically? E.g. `AppURL::to('assets/css/website.min.css');`